# remove input field with this.id X

Tags: javascript, jquery

css

```
.inactive {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    .active {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }
```

html output

```
<img class="responsive-img playlist inactive" id="<?php echo $row->tafel_id;?>" src="<?php echo $src; ?>">
```

js click function

```
$(".playlist").click(function() {
if( $(this).hasClass('inactive') ){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('<input>').attr({type: 'hidden', name: 'tafel_id', value: $(this).attr('id')}).appendTo('form');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('inactive');
    var input = "<input value="+'"'+$(this).attr('id')+'"'+">";
    $(input).remove();
}});
```

Error in `$(input).remove();`

For example

```
<input value="268">
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: there's no selector like `$('<input>')` . maybe you want `$('input')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like

```
$("input[value='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").remove();
```

It will remove the input field where `value` will be `$(this).attr("id");`

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you're trying to do 2 things in your code.

1- Toggle between two classes. 
You are writing extra lines of code for that. You can still achieve that in just one line

To toggle between two classes, you should use

```
$(element).toggleClass("inactive active");
```

2- Remove input field where you are clicking.

And to remove `input` field you can use

```
$("#"+ $(this).attr("id")).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `$(input).remove();` and add following code. because you already assigned a name for the input. so you can delete it by name

```
$('[name="tafel_id"]').remove();
```